# How can I gain more insight into my users and what endpoints they are hitting in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have an application in Azure with two parts - a static web app hosting my front end and an app service handling my API.

I'm trying to get more insight into my users (AD-authenticated) on the app service side, to see what endpoints they are hitting, when, and where from. My understanding was that the application insights being enabled would provide me this, however, all I see is one user (some kind of proxy user when my static web app calls the backend app service?) and no relevant user data.

Why is my app service only getting one user in the app insights view and how can I change this to get the real number of authenticated users to pop up to parse thru their metrics?

So far I've sifted thru the documentation, tried linking my static web app to the app service via APIs, etc. with no luck...

Answer (score 1):

The Application Insights JS SDK can be configured to automatically track `fetch` requests made by your static web app.

First, make sure the [`SDK Configuration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript-sdk-configuration#sdk-configuration) that you are using isn't disabling any of the default tracking available.

Specifically, check the `disableFetchTracking` (or `disableAjaxTracking`/`disableXhr` depending on how your app is making requests) setting.

Here is the notice for the above setting that *might* be affecting auto tracking for you

> The default setting for `disableFetchTracking` is `false`, meaning it's enabled. However, in versions prior to 2.8.10, it was disabled by default. When set to `true`, Fetch requests aren't automatically collected. The default setting changed from `true` to `false` in version 2.8.0.

As for tracking authenticated users, you would need to set the user context in the App Insights SDK as shown in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#authenticated-users).

Comment: I may not understand the way Application Insight works, but do I have to use the SDK for this use case? Can I use the out-of-the-box functionality that I get by linking an app service to an application insights service in the portal settings?